# Ng-outlet cannot access parent $scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, components, angular-component-router

Using Angular's standard route I was able to have child controllers access the parent $scope:

```
<div ng-controller="ParentCtrl">
    <ng-view></ng-view>
</div>
```

Any Child controllers within `ng-view` would be able to access the ParentCtrl Data, but with the Angular 1.5 Component Router this doesnt seem like the case. The only difference in the above markup is instead of `ng-view` it's `ng-outlet`.

Does anyone know how to access Parent Controller information within a Child Controller based in an `ng-outlet` in the Component Router? Or is there any other way to access parent data?

Answer (score 0):

you can try `$rootScope` for your case

Comment: So I'd set the parent data to $rootScope and access that $rootScope variable within a child controller? I always thought accessing $rootScope to be bad practise?

Comment: i don't think so, i always call $rootScope variable. Why do you think it is bad practice?

Comment: http://www.thinkingmedia.ca/2015/01/learn-how-to-use-scopes-properly-in-angularjs/ This link give a run-down on $rootScope and potentially the issues of assigning variables to it.